# How do I get notification when a Facebook friend installed an app

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I am writing an iOS app and authentication is handled by Facebook SDK. I want to get an notification in my App when a friend of mine starts using the app. How do I retrieve this information from API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can authorize users with `user_friends`, use `/me/friends` to get all the friends who authorized the App too and then send a message to all the friends in the list if the user is new.